# Match file name using RegEx

Tags: c#, regex

I am a newbie in Regular Expression and this is my scenario:
I want to match one of below lines using RegEx:

```
20130516-003-v5i32.exe
20130516-003-v5i64.exe
```

The above lines have this form :
The first part is `date`, second part is fixed, and third one is `v5i` + one of `32 or 64` + `.exe`

The first thing I want to achieve is to match the above form using RexEx in a URL like :

```
http://definitions.symantec.com/defs/20130516-003-v5i32.exe
http://definitions.symantec.com/defs/20130516-003-v5i64.exe
```

I wrote a simple RegEx for matching but it seems that it is wrong:

```
\d{8}-\d{3}-v5i[3-6][2-4]\.exe
```

Then extract the theme and assign it into a variable; for example:

```
var date=new DateTime(2013,05,16);
var version=32; 
,...
```

How can I do that?

Comment: http://www.regexplained.co.uk/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To extract certain values you may use [Regex groups](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bs2twtah.aspx), eg:

```
string s = @"http://definitions.symantec.com/defs/20130516-003-v5i32.exe";
Match m = Regex.Match(s, @"(\d{4})(\d{2})(\d{2})");
    DateTime date = new DateTime(
    Int32.Parse(m.Groups[1].Value),
    Int32.Parse(m.Groups[2].Value),
    Int32.Parse(m.Groups[3].Value));
```

There's also Named Group feature `(?<groupName>)`:

```
Match m = Regex.Match(s, @"(?<year>\d{4})(?<month>\d{2})(?<day>\d{2})");
DateTime date = new DateTime(
    Int32.Parse(m.Groups["year"].Value),
    Int32.Parse(m.Groups["month"].Value),
    Int32.Parse(m.Groups["day"].Value));
```

Answer (score 2):

Since your patterns only end in v5i32.exe or v5i64.exe, you need:

```
\d{8}-\d{3}-v5i(32|64)\.exe
```

The pipe symbol | gives you alternation, while the parentheses provide for grouping. A nice summary of regex operations is [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/reference.html).

Comment: +1 It would be even better if you could add the grouping to show how to extract the relevant portions.

Answer (score 1):

I modified the regex as follows

```
\d{8}-\d{3}-v5i[3][2]\.exe
```

and it's matching the following string:

```
20130516-003-v5i32.exe
```

and

```
\d{8}-\d{3}-v5i[6][4]\.exe
```

matches the following string:

```
20130516-003-v5i64.exe
```

Here's a useful tool to test regex:

http://gskinner.com/RegExr/